# telnet to port 80 (nginx), with forward to apache2 at port 8080, fails with 'connection closed by foreign host' and no explanations seemingly anywhere

Tags: nginx, php, apache2, html, javascript

i'm running an Kubuntu 22.04 server, and want to shuttle LAN-only traffic from port 80, served as far as i can tell by nginx, to port 8080 served by apache2 (for PHP purposes).

but i'm getting this "connection closed by foreign host" (presumably from nginx), that's proving a complete show-stopper at port 80.
i can still access the PHP and code filetree that i need to access by addressing port 8080 directly in the browser, but i do wonder what's causing this.

any help would be much appreciated. :)

```
root@parakeet:/var/log/nginx# netstat -tulpn | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3001930/nginx: mast 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3001930/nginx: mast 
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      3001981/apache2  

root@parakeet:/var/log/nginx# cat error.log
root@parakeet:/var/log/nginx# ls -al | grep error.log
-rw-r-----  1 www-data adm          0 jul  2 21:09 error.log

root@parakeet:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# cat 000-localhost.conf 
#
# Note: This file must be loaded before other virtual host config files.
# HTTPS
server {
  listen 80 http2;
  listen [::]:80 http2;

  server_name 192.168.178.29;
  root /var/www/192.168.178.29;
    
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://192.168.178.29:8080/;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;

    proxy_connect_timeout 159s;
    proxy_send_timeout   60;
    proxy_read_timeout   60;
    send_timeout 60;
    resolver_timeout 60;
  }
}

root@parakeet:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# cat 000-localhost.conf 
<VirtualHost 192.168.178.29:8080>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName 192.168.178.29

        ServerAdmin rene.veerman.netherlands@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/192.168.178.29

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
        LogLevel info ssl:warn

        SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" forwarded
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.8080.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.8080.log combined env=!forwarded
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.8080.log forwarded env=forwarded

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".

        <Directory /var/www/192.168.178.29>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

[HTTP/2 is usually supported by web browsers in combination with encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2#Encryption)  so not something you would enable on the plain HTTP port, port 80. So you nginx configuration:

```
server {
   listen 80 http2;
```

should omit the http2 directive:

```
server {
   listen 80;
```

As to why currently you **can't telnet to port 80**: Unlike plain HTTP 1.1 which you can easily emulate by entering HTTP commands with telnet or HTTPS/1.1 which you can similarly test with for example `openssl s_client -connect host:443` ; is HTTP/2 more difficult to test.

HTTP/2 is no longer a text based protocol, but rather a more efficient binary protocol  so telnet doesn't provide the correct handshake to successfully establish a connection. See: https://blog.cloudflare.com/tools-for-debugging-testing-and-using-http-2/ for some examples to use instead.

---

Typically you [allow Apache to listen](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html) either to all IP-addresses and interfaces on a system with `Listen 8080` OR in the configuration you describe one  binds Apache httpd specifically to localhost so it cannot be accessed remotely with `Listen 127.0.0.1:8080`. Either way rather than:  `VirtualHost 192.168.178.29:8080` you'd typically use `<VirtualHost *:8080>`.

Second, the apache VirtualHost definition you post doesn't appear to support HTTPS and I assume that when *"addressing port 8080 directly in the browser"* you also use a clear text HTTP URI.

Then using trying to use `proxy_pass https://192.168.178.29:8080/;` ; with HTTPS in your nginx reverse proxy is doomed to fail. That should also be plain HTTP: `proxy_pass http://192.168.178.29:8080/;`  and when apache and nginx run on the same server even: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big expert in this field, but I'll just assume that the problem may be that you need to enable the ssl directive for nginx.

`listen 80 ssl http2;`

You also need to make sure that you have enabled the ssl module for apache.

I would start looking for a problem by replacing https with http and making sure it works over this protocol.

Comment: Indeed http2 more or less requires ssl, or rather web browser use http/2 in conjunction with TLS, but I wouldn't recommend running SSL on the plain http port, port 80. So I'd rather recommend to not use the http2 directive there.

Comment: except you can't get a certificate for a LAN IP address. you'd have to open a NAT port, exposing the LAN code filetree to the world, i think..